# CefSharp: EvaluateScriptAsync hanging?

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, google-chrome, cefsharp

I am visting the Twitter profile page and I am trying to detect if the logged in user has followed the profile they're viewing, can someone tell me why the Followed() method is hanging and not returning anything? I've waited up to 10 minutes for it to return something but it hasn't?

I can't imagine a situation where it would take 10 minutes to process so something must be stopping it from returning something, can anyone help?

```
private bool Followed()
{
    JavascriptResponse js = EvaluateScript("document.getElementsByClassName('ProfileNav-item--userActions')[0].children[0].children[0].className");
    return !js.Result.ToString().Contains("not-following");
}

JavascriptResponse EvaluateScript(string script)
{
    var task = _browser.EvaluateScriptAsync(script);
    task.Wait();
    return task.Result;
}
```

I think js.Result or js may possibly be null, but why would it be? That's the real question here.

Comment: Whats on development console or in debug.log?